# how do i do load model to multiclass classification in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i want to load my model and doing a test of my model, ive tried in binary class and it work then i tried to using multiclass but it didnt work, can anyone tell me how to solve this

```
 json_file = open('modelBiometrik.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("modelBiometrik.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

# evaluate loaded model on test data
loaded_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(x1, y1, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (loaded_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

ive tried to find in the internet but i didnt find it thank you for your help

i got this error

```
File "C:\Users\lord bramasta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (15,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: Did you re-train your model with multi-class training data or trained a binary classifier and trying to use that model for multi-class classification?

Comment: i did retrain and i update the error

Comment: Can you please share the model summary. The error suggest that the dense layer was expecting 15 as shape but got just 1. Also if possible share the code OR at least the reproducible code to help. Thank You.

Comment: Have you update the last dense layer with shape 15?The error say the last layer have shape one..

Comment: thank you i solved this problem with encoding of my class